# else without previous if error in c++

Tags: c++

Can someone please explain me the above error in this code?  I get it in CodeBlocks and when I use Visual Studio it says expected a statement.
Thank you so much.

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        char fruits;
        float sales;

        cout << " Enter the First letter of the Fruit's name : ";
        cin >> fruits;

        cout << " Enter the amount of sales : ";
        cin >> sales;


        if (fruits == 'A' || fruits == 'a')
            cout << " You are selling Apples ";
            cout << " Your commission is " << sales*(4.5 / 100) << " rupees. ";

        else if (fruits == 'P' || fruits == 'p')
            cout << " You are selling Pears";
            cout << " Your commission is " << sales*(5 / 100) << " rupees. ";

        else if (fruits == 'O' || fruits == 'o')
            cout << " You are selling Oranges ";
            cout << " Your commission is " << sales*(5.5 / 100) << " rupees. ";

        else if (fruits == 'G' || fruits == 'g')
            cout << " You are selling Grapes ";
            cout << " Your commission is " << sales*(6 / 100) << " rupees. ";

        else
            cout << " Invalid Entry. Try again. ";


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: How do you make a block containing multiple statements? If you don't know that, you need to go back to your book and read it from the beginning.

Comment: C++ isn't Python, you know?

Comment: It's as if someone here works for Apple, isn't it? Missing braces are somehow connected to fruits.. At least here it causes a compiler error rather than a [goto fail](http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/) runtime bug.

Comment: **Ahhhrg!** Apple style again: `goto jail; goto jail;` ...

Answer (score 5):

You need to use braces on your `if` statements, like this

```
if (fruits == 'A' || fruits == 'a') {
        cout << " You are selling Apples ";
        cout << " Your commission is " << sales*(4.5 / 100) << " rupees. ";
} else if (fruits == 'P' || fruits == 'p') {

} // and so on
```

Because otherwise your `if` clauses will only be valid for the following next line, which would make your logic looks something like this:

```
if () 
    cout << " I am only getting executed if the above 'if' statement is true ";
cout << " I will always be executed, no matter what ";
```

And, by doing so, your `else` statements would be loose in the middle of your code, resulting in the compilation error that you are getting

```
if () 
    cout << " I am only getting executed if the above 'if' statement is true ";
cout << " I will always be executed, no matter what ";
else // but, else what? There is no 'if' behind me
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because you have a multi-line block without the enclosing curly braces. C++ interprets this

```
if (fruits == 'A' || fruits == 'a')
    cout << " You are selling Apples ";
    cout << " Your commission is " << sales*(4.5 / 100) << " rupees. ";
```

like this:

```
if (fruits == 'A' || fruits == 'a')
    cout << " You are selling Apples "; // Protected by `if`
// Not protected by `if` !!!
cout << " Your commission is " << sales*(4.5 / 100) << " rupees. ";
```

C++ compiler ignores indentation; that is why when you put an `else` after the second `cout`, it is treated as an `else` without a preceding `if`.

To fix this problem, enclose all blocks protected by `if`s in curly braces. It is a good idea to get in a habit of doing it even for cases when the braces are not required, because `if` protects a single statement.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, the code

```
if (fruits == 'A' || fruits == 'a')
    cout << " You are selling Apples ";
    cout << " Your commission is " << sales*(4.5 / 100) << " rupees. ";
```

is interpreted as

```
if (fruits == 'A' || fruits == 'a') cout << " You are selling Apples ";
cout << " Your commission is " << sales*(4.5 / 100) << " rupees. ";
```

In other words, only the first statement is guarded by the `if` statement. The second statement executes unconditionally. This explains the error you're getting - the `else if`s you have don't match up with an earlier `if` statement.

To fix this, add braces around the bodies of your `if` statements:

```
if (fruits == 'A' || fruits == 'a') {
    cout << " You are selling Apples ";
    cout << " Your commission is " << sales*(4.5 / 100) << " rupees. ";
}
```

More generally, indentation is irrelevant in C++, so be careful to make sure that your indentation matches your expected intent.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated answer. It fixed the error. Thanks :))